# Is it possible to enable esm when using Gulp to build the TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, gulp, ts-node

I am using Gulp to build the project like this:

```
gulp build
```

I want to enable the ts-node esm, so I add the configuration in `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
"ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
```

When I rerun the build command, it seems Gulp did not read the `tsconfig.json` esm configuration. What should I do to enable the esm when using Gulp to build the project? This is the Gulp version:

```
> gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

This is the full config of `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "tests", "third_party"]
}
```